# Shortcut to Clean up folder by Name?

Tags: keyboard, automator

I would like to create a keyboard shortcut to Clean Up Folder by Name. Which can be done by right-click > Clean up by > Name

What is the Automator code needed to achieve this ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On my Mac (running 10.7 Lion), there's already a default shortcut for this, ⌥⌘1 (<kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>). You can access the **Clean Up By** menu under the Finder's **View** menu, which will show the shortcuts assigned:
[image: Clean Up By menu]

*Note that this option is only available on the Desktop or a Finder window in *Icons* mode (not List, Column or Cover Flow modes).*

If you don't have shortcuts assigned by default, [you can add them in the **Application Shortcuts** section of **Keyboard Preferences**](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3957).

Comment: Thats perfect. However I have a question, how do you have shortcuts showing beside the options ?? I Do not have that (hence I asked this question) - Mountain Lion OSX 10.8.2 --- EDIT oops I was looking by right clicking .. apparently clicking on the menu bar shows the shortcuts

Comment: This is all of a sudden removed for me..